# How do t-lymphocytes become mature if thymus has lost its function?

Tags: physiology

The development of t-lymphocytes are done by thymus and we also know that the thymus degenerates before puberty and we also know the maximum lifespan of WBC's is 15 days. So, how do t-lymphocytes become mature if thymus has lost his function?

Answer (score 2):

A few points, I'll expand on this later and add references if I have time:

1. The thymus starts degenerating at puberty but continues to function in thymocyte maturation for decades, albeit at a lower level
2. Many mature T cells can live for years
3. Through homeostatic proliferation, peripheral T cells maintain their population size
4. Immune surveillance generally decreases with age

Note that extended lifespans and homeostatic proliferation (points 2 and 3) don't contribute to TCR diversity but only maintain the existing repertoire.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is this: yes, the thymus involutes at puberty but that doesn't halt  thymopoiesis. The thymus continues to produce naive T lymphocytes throughout our lives (even up to 70 years of age-see references) albeit at a very reduced rate. This mechanism is very important for example in HIV-infected individuals who are still able to repopulate their immune cells through a combination of peripheral T cell division and thymic production of naive T cells.

References: [Reference_1](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v396/n6712/full/396690a0.html), [Reference_2](http://www.impactaging.com/papers/v2/n2/full/100122.html#bibl_1), [Reference_3](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0531556514000060)